# yii2 bootstrap dropdown from model

Tags: php, yii2

Been at this for some time. I am trying to set-up a drowndown box. I can't get to fully understand how I should fill it... Here's the link of the documentation: [Dropdown](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-bootstrap-dropdown.html).

```
//$chapters[chapter['id','title','parent_id']]
echo Dropdown::widget([
'items'=>$chapters,
'options'=>'',
]);
```

When I try this I need a label, but when I add a label, Yii says it doesn't recognize label.

I just can't get it to work and since yii2 is pretty new it is hard to find examples online.

Comment: How do you add the label?

Comment: I've tried several things, like:
    echo Dropdown::widget([
    'label'=>'labelname',
    'items'=>$chapters,
Or:
    echo Dropdown::widget([
    'items'=>['label'=>'labelname',$chapters].

I think the problem is something with $chapters being an array. I am not sure how to cope with that. I miss seeing the for loop there for myself, now it just happens in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
echo Html::activeDropDownList($model, 'id',
  ArrayHelper::map(Chapter::find()->all(), 'id', 'title'));
```

I am not using the DropDown::Widget, but this does (exactly?) the same thing.
Next step it to give the ArrayHelper from the Controller, instead of getting from the database directly from the view. But for now this works.

Answer (score 1):

echo Dropdown will never show you a label. 
Either use an activeField or manually show it using `echo Html::label()`, You can read more about the params for the label here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#label()-detail

You usually can use an activeField, or at least active models

Comment: Eventually I need it in an activeField yes. I want to use it to select a parent chapter and be able to add child chapters to the parent chapter.

The problem for me is how do I translate it from the documentation to actual code.. I am new to the whole Yii Framework, it throws me off my game..

Comment: why not use Gii to create the code for you? It is easy to use and it is the perfect example on how things work.

Comment: I did not know something like that existed. I read most, not all of the guide. I'll look into this!

Comment: It is quite nice, you can also extend it to make it work like you want to. Also it is a good learning tool because it is the best example possible with your own tables.